# Query regarding local and global variables in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. Please see the below code:

```
for line in range(8):
    fact = 1
print(fact)
```

I received output as `1`

My query is since `fact` variable is withing the scope of for loop, how does Python access the variable outside it's scope. Thank in advance.

Comment: for loop doesn't have its own scope ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules

Comment: `for` loops don't create a scope (apart from comprehensions in python 3)

Answer (score 1):

Python has function-level scoping, not block-level. With a few exceptions, local variables are local to the whole of the enclosing function.